# Fast login to application (magic url alternatives)

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, web-application

**I am searching for fast ways to log into web applications(or start being logged).**

Applications use cookie authentication stored in db that expire after some time. Magic url for login instantly is not allowed option.

I prefer start being logged into application(without log in every time). I prefer solution that not change applications login elements.

I think about changing cookie expire time in database, still I want to to know how other solve simillar problems.

Comment: Well, it depends on your application. Even if you mimic a cookie for a logged-in session, the application may well do server-side checks to see whether it should trust your login session. You may need to ask your developers.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be doing tests that verify the user's frontend experience, correct? Functional tests of some sort? That means you're probably going to have to authenticate like a user would, at least once.

A few tips:

- You can avoid automating the login form if you capture the HTTP request generated when you click "submit" and playing it back. This will save a little bit of time waiting for the login page to load.
- You can store the cookie and re-use the same cookie between tests. This may cause state leakage between tests, but it will save some time if logging in is resource-intensive. Store the cookie information some place all your tests can get at it, like inside a static class or in a file. Have each test attempt to use the cookie and, if they get rejected, log in normally. That way, only the first test that runs after a cookie expires has to log in normally, and the rest can piggyback on that.

Answer (score -1):

What about [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)? It is

1. Free and open source
2. Mutithreaded by design
3. Provides [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) to deal with cookie-based authentication
4. Provides [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser) so it could act like a spider

Comment: I know JMeter could log by with HTTP, still I want gives tester way to not log every time, so I prefer start with logged cookie(almost empty site for http login is to some level solution, still I prefer not call it). Loading logged cookie into browser seems simpler.

Comment: It is possible to load cookies i.e. from [CSV file](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) and send them along with the request.

Comment: This question is asking about techniques; throwing tools at a problem only helps if you know what you're trying to use it for.